# In context of CQRS and DDD how would you handle slightly varying use cases?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I could have a command for each variation or I could have one command and handle variations within it.

To illustrate, I have three use cases (or more), "CommentOnPhoto", "CommentOnWall", "CommentOnArticle". All of them internally use the same commenting system. The difference between three is:

- Different policy needs to be checked (`CommentOnPhotoPolicy`, `CommentOnWallPolicy`, `CommentOnArticlePolicy`)
- Different aggregate has to be pulled from repository so that we could call, `photo.attachComment(comment)`, `article.attachComment(comment)`, etc.

If going the route of one command for each variation then should each command inherit from some base `CommentOnSomething` command since they are all very similar?

If going the route of one mother command for all use cases then we will have to make use of Service Locator to pull needed Policies and Repositories on demand (we don't want to inject 10+ dependencies for each use case only to use one). Is this acceptable if we make use of abstract factories and such to hide away service locator use? Meaning we have `CommentPolicyFactory` and `CommentableFactory` which use Service Locator internally to deliver the right policy and the right aggregate.

Comment: I would not call it "slightly" if I have different policies and aggreagtes. It depends on your domain but your example can have even 3 different bounded context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One command per variation.

I would first focus on creating a very generic "commenting" component (as its own project, decoupled from your core domain). Once you have it, then your commands `CommentOnPhoto`, `CommentsOnWall` and others will become very simple with just a few lines of code.

Comment: That's the way I chose to go. The only issue I have with this is that now there are a lot of command handlers and command definitions as well as controller methods to service all use cases.

Comment: @DenisPshenov Good for you. You are closed to Object Calisthenics. Your system can turn into microservices and/or event driven easily and will help alot in scalability in general.